# function to choose between iframe.src and iframe.contentwindow.location

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm using `iframe.get(0).contentWindow.location` to get the current url of an iframe. The problem is, if the user navigated away from the original domain, this raises an error. How can I tell js/jquery to then use `iframe.src` instead?

TIA!

Comment: If `iframe` is a jQuery object, you can easily do `iframe.attr('src')`

Comment: @LightStyle src will only give you the original url. contentwindow has the advantage that as long as it's in the same domain, you'll get the latest url to be loaded in the iframe.

Answer (score 3):

You need to `try` getting the `contentWindow`'s `location`:

```
try {src = iframe.get(0).contentWindow.location.href;}
catch(e) {src = iframe.get(0).src;}
```

Comment: Looks like I was to hasty :-(. It's working fine in FF, but it doesn't work in Chrome. Can you think of a solution?

Comment: Well, I'd need to know what `iframe` is.

Comment: I have an iframe with `id="thisifr"`. So I used your code above with `$("#thisifr").get` etc.

Comment: Try `iframe = document.getElementById('thisifr')` and drop the `.get(0)`

Comment: Didn't work. As soon as the webpage loaded is from a different domain, Chrome doesn't return a url.